# Getting mouse position in keyboard event

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to have a selection wheel appear when the user holds down the Shift key.

The wheel should be centred on the mouse's position.

However when I test this, `pageX` and `clientX` are both undefined on the event object.

Is it possible to get the mouse coordinates on a keyboard event?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, simply track `mousemove` events and continuously save the current position in case you get a keyboard event.

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution that doesn't rely on jQuery :p I hate jQuery...

Comment: Hehe, I do too, secretly. :-)

Comment: This again assumes that the user moves the mouse. What happens when a user presses the shift key alone?

Comment: @arviman I doubt there is any way to get the mouse position if the mouse has never been moved?

Comment: OK write the code for your solution with and without jQuery then compare them in case of browser compatibility and amount of code you wrote

Comment: @arviman - [key events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-keyboardevents) don't have an associated position, only mouse and wheel events do. Note that the included reference is to the [W3C DOM 3 Events Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/), which is just a working draft but reasonably summarises what browsers do.

Comment: @Mohsen - look at the answers - how much more code is there in the POJS solutions? Not much, and you save loading 100kb and 4,000 lines of library code.

Comment: @RobG but that non-jQuery code don't work in IE8 then you need to write attachEvent for IE too.

Comment: @Mohsen - done, and compatible back to IE 6 at least. A whole 6 lines of code pulled from a modular library.

Answer (score 3):

Cache mouse position in a global variable in every `mousemove` event and use it when a key event fires:

```
var mousePosition = {x:0, y:0};
$(document).bind('mousemove',function(mouseMoveEvent){
mousePosition.x = mouseMoveEvent.pageX;
mousePosition.y = mouseMoveEvent.pageY;
});
$(document).bind('keyup', function(keyUpEvent){
  $('body').append($('<p/>').text('x:' + mousePosition.x + ' * y: ' + mousePosition.y));
});
```

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/uxecuj/4

JavaScript without jQuery:

```
var mousePosition = {x:0, y:0};
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(mouseMoveEvent){
  mousePosition.x = mouseMoveEvent.pageX;
  mousePosition.y = mouseMoveEvent.pageY;
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(keyUpEvent){
  var divLog = document.querySelector('#log'),
      log = 'x:' + mousePosition.x + ' * y: ' + mousePosition.y,
      p = document.createElement('p').innerHTM = log;
  divLog.appendChild(p);
}, false);
```

Comment: This only triggers the function on a `keyup`. I believe it should change when the user presses the key. Also, the `mousemove` event does not fire when the user doesn't move the mouse. So the mousePosition object's property is not set when the user only presses the key.

Comment: This is same solution as you selected as answer. You blind hate jQuery

Comment: Oh i didn't ask the question. And i personally love jQuery.

Comment: The real problem is that keyboard events are only required to dispatch an event into the DOM if an element that can receive keyboard events is focused. Otherwise, nothing will happen since no event will be dispatched.

Answer (score 1):

Cache the mouse position.

```
var x = 0, y = 0;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    x = e.pageX
    y = e.pageY;
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    console.log(x + ' ' + y);
}, false);
```

Or with JS Ninja Library.

```
var x = 0, y = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    x = e.pageX
    y = e.pageY;
});
$(document).keypressed(function() {
    console.log(x + ' ' + y);
});
```

Comment: With jQuery. Cuz its awesome :)

Comment: This thread got a lot of jQuery love/hate, I wonder where the people stand 6 years later :)

Comment: what's a jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the POJS equivalent of other answers that is cross browser back to IE 6 (and probably IE 5 but I don't have it to test any more). No global variables even:

```
function addEvent(el, evt, fn) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
  } else if (el.attachEvent) {
    el.attachEvent('on' + evt, fn);
  }
}


(function () {
  var x, y;
  window.onload = function() {
    addEvent(document.body, 'mousemove', function(e) {
      // Support IE event model
      e = e || window.event;
      x = e.pageX || e.clientX;  
      y = e.pageY || e.clientY;
    });

    // Show coords, assume element with id "d0" exists
    addEvent(document.body, 'keypress', function() {
      document.getElementById('d0').innerHTML = x + ',' + y;
    });
  }
}());
```

But there are bigger issues. Key events are only dispatched if an element that can receive keyboard input is focused (input, textarea, and so on). Also, if the user scrolls the screen without moving the mouse, the coordinates will probably be wrong.

An alternative solution is to use CSS to replace the cursor with a custom animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can do the following (assuming you have an image with `id="wheelImage"` and whose `position` is set to `absolute`), write the following inside your keydown event. Here we use the global properties pageX and pageY that are passed to any handler. You can also use jQuery's `shiftKey` property to check if the shift key has been pressed.

```
$().keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey) { 
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#wheelImage').css('left',e.pageX ).css('top', e.pageY);
  }  
});
```