# How to get page cursor position in Input Box

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-events

Given a Javascript `keyup` event in an `input` box, how do I determine where on the screen that blinking cursor is? I'm trying to position a popup box based off of that cursor position inside the input box.

For mouse clicks I get `pageX` and `pageY` properties, but not for key events.

The best thing I can think of now is to find the position of the input box and do some math based off of the 0-index cursor position (`event.target.selectionStart`)

Comment: You talk about blinking cursor inside input or mouse cursor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting mouse position in keyboard event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562503/getting-mouse-position-in-keyboard-event)

Comment: @MTK The blinking cursor

Comment: This Github link https://github.com/component/textarea-caret-position seems a good fit to the problem.